# Bind Set Port for Forwarders

Tags: bind, port, named-conf

According to http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/queries.html#forwarders the port can be specified after the address.

However when i try to set it to

```
forwarders {
    127.0.0.1 2053;
}
```

named-checkconf returns

```
/etc/bind/named.conf.options:12: missing ';' before '2053'
/etc/bind/named.conf.options:12: expected IP address near '2053'
```

My Fulls named.conf.options file:

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    dnssec-validation no;
    auth-nxdomain no;
    recursion yes;
    allow-recursion { any; };
    allow-query { any; };
    allow-query-cache { any; };
    listen-on { any; };
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    forwarders {
            127.0.0.1 2053;
    };
};
```

Comment: I think the correct syntax would be `127.0.0.1 port 2053;`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `port` keyword.

```
forwarders {
            127.0.0.1 port 2053;
    };
```